# Redirect to specific controller if url starts with xyz in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I need to redirect to specific url in Laravel if the url starts with content or video or picture or videos or pictures or etc...

I have written this concept in plain php but how this can be written in Laravel.

**redirect.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
    $link = $_GET['name'];
    $request = parse_url($link);
    echo $request["path"];
} 
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /content/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /videos/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /video/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /contents/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} //contents/
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/redirect.php?name=http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,QSA,B]
```

**Examples**

```
http://localhost:8048/content/23423/nice-up-civic-poll.html
http://localhost:8048/video/43432/something-here.html
http://localhost:8048/videos/2354323/good-nice.html
http://localhost:8048/contents/451425/breakup-actor.html
http://localhost:8048/content/time/451425/breakup-actor.html
http://localhost:8048/video/watch/1233456/accident-occured.html
```

Comment: can you write a sample url for this case

Comment: @DhavalChheda updated the question

Comment: Well, what have you tried? What you want is all written in the documentation.

Comment: @Jeffrey I tried placing the code in .htaccess file in laravel's public folder but nothing seems to work and created 1 route like this ->  **Route::get('/{name?}', 'HomeController@index');**

Comment: make simple if Request::segment(1) == "video" .... you mean this ?

Comment: @PatrikHorváth no

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your routes like this:

```
Route::get("/content/{path}", ...)->where("path", ".*");
Route::get("/video/{path}", ...)->where("path", ".*");
Route::get("/picture/{path}", ...)->where("slug", ".*");
```

Comment: redirects to laravel 404 page... did it work for you if so did u make any other changes in .htaccess file or any other file

Comment: use the default .htaccess file provided when installing laravel

Comment: **Route::get('/{any}', function ($any) {
        return "nice";
    })->where('any', '.*');**  this seems to work but doesn't handle the extension

Comment: PaulSantos seems to work but doesn't handle the extension. If .html is removed it works but how to handle the extension part.